# How to start webrick server in verbose mode for a rails app to see the HTTP request/response header on console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I am developing an API for one of my android app in rails. I am trying to keep the user session active through the cookies what warden/devise has already implemented for it, through out the all subsequent request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for thin server :
thin start -V

BTW, we can get it with thin --help